# How to call the parent boolean with function to child in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have `boolean` which is the `toggleUnit` and I have a function which is the `onSwitch()`. I also used `nz-switch` for the weather it its `Fahrenheit` or `Celcius`

***list.component.html***

```
<nz-switch [(ngModel)]="toggleUnit" nzCheckedChildren="&deg;F" nzUnCheckedChildren="&deg;C" (ngModelChange)="onSwitchChange()"></nz-switch>
 <div class="weather">
    <app-weather></app-weather>
</div>
```

***list.component.ts***

```
toggleUnit: boolean = false;
onSwitchChange() {
  switch (this.toggleUnit) {
     case true: {
       this.toggleUnit = true;
     }case false: {
       this.toggleUnit = false;
     }
  }
}
```

***weather.component.ts***

```
ngOnInit() {
    //console.log(this.toggleUnit);
    //trying to get the parent ``toggleUnit`` value, if its true or false
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to pass the value to your child component

**list.component.html**

```
<nz-switch [(ngModel)]="toggleUnit" nzCheckedChildren="&deg;F" nzUnCheckedChildren="&deg;C" (ngModelChange)="onSwitchChange()"></nz-switch>

<div class="weather">
  <app-weather [toggleUnit]="toggleUnit"></app-weather>
</div>
```

**weather.component.ts**

```
@Input() toggleUnit: boolean;

ngOnInit() {
  //console.log(this.toggleUnit);
  //trying to get the parent ``toggleUnit`` value, if its true or false
}

ngOnChanges(value) {
  // called when toggleUnit is updated from parent
  console.log(value);
  console.log(this.toggleUnit);
}
```

Comment: but sir, when I click the button its doesn't change.

Comment: I have nz-switch which is ```<nz-switch [(ngModel)]="toggleUnit" nzCheckedChildren="&deg;F" nzUnCheckedChildren="&deg;C" (ngModelChange)="onSwitchChange()"></nz-switch>```

Comment: Updated with change emitter

Comment: I got an error ```Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1``` <boolean>

Comment: Ah I see what you're trying. Give me a moment :)

Comment: fixed sir. how'bout when you check in childComponent if its changed

Comment: What I original had should work. Changes in the parent component should automatically be seen in the child. If you want to listen for the changes you can use ngOnChanges in the child

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200928/discussion-between-abc-and-abney317).